# How to speed up a .py script refering to millions of files?

Tags: python, bash

I have about 2.5M files to process with a .py script.

I'm using super calculator but I the problem is not the power, its the python process itself that open and close every time and loosing time.

I'm using a loop to get every files in a folder that I want to convert with the script. So the ${line} refers to a file where every line is referring to every files of the folder.

Is there a way to process all files after opening the .py script instead of looping the python script?

There is my loop code :

```
### LOOP ###
while :
do
pythonsh ${RAMDISK}/script.py -l ${RAMDISK}/${line}.pdb -U '' -A hydrogens

done

exit
```

The python script is only a tool to convert .pdb to .pdbqt files that I've found from AutodockTools which comes with Autodock4.

Comment: You ask for Python script, but you show bash script? How to try to help?

Comment: Is your question how to do a loop in Python?

Comment: If the bottle neck is the process management of the Python script, then just move the looping to the Python script so it no longer needs to open and close all the time.

Comment: also if you are looking for help adding functionality to the script, we would need a link to the script to help further

Comment: The "setting PYTHONHOME environment" taking for ever. Here's the python script : http://wind.isi.edu/marbles/assets/components/workflow_portal/users/lib/MGLTools/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_ligand4.py

Comment: What do you mean @poke ?

Comment: Instead of having bash call the script N times to do X, just let bash call the script once and le the script do X N times.

Comment: I've tried pythonsh script.py -l folder/* and it saids argument list was too long, Do you see an other way?

Comment: You might be able to do something like find folder/ | xargs pythonsh script.py -i but A) that's serverfault territory and B) may not help if the python script has a limit... you really should post the main portion of the python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the script, adding a `-i` commandline option.

This will let you specify a text file containing ligand filenames (one per line) and process them all without restarting Python.

You should now be able to call it as

```
pythonsh ./newscript.py -i ./list_of_files.txt -U '' -A hydrogens
```

NOTE: this is untested! It should work as given, but be VERY cautious!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# 
#
# $Header: /opt/cvs/python/packages/share1.5/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_ligand4.py,v 1.5.4.1 2009/04/15 17:41:57 rhuey Exp $
#
# Modified 2016/02/07
# Hugh Bothwell  http://stackoverflow.com/users/33258
# Added -i commandline option to process multiple files
#
import os 

from MolKit import Read
from AutoDockTools.MoleculePreparation import AD4LigandPreparation

# initialize command-line parameters
#-l: ligand
ligand_filename =  None
#-i: file containing ligand-filenames
ligand_listfile =  None
# optional parameters
verbose = None
add_bonds = False
#-A: repairs to make: add bonds and/or hydrogens
repairs = ""
#-C  default: add gasteiger charges 
charges_to_add = 'gasteiger'
#-p preserve charges on specific atom types
preserve_charge_types=''
#-U: cleanup by merging nphs_lps, nphs, lps
cleanup  = "nphs_lps"
#-B named rotatable bond type(s) to allow to rotate
#allowed_bonds = ""
allowed_bonds = "backbone"
#-r  root
root = 'auto'
#-o outputfilename
outputfilename = None
#-F check_for_fragments
check_for_fragments = False
#-I bonds_to_inactivate
bonds_to_inactivate = ""
#-Z inactivate_all_torsions
inactivate_all_torsions = False
#-g attach_nonbonded_fragments
attach_nonbonded_fragments = False
#-m mode 
mode = 'automatic'
#-d dictionary
dict = None

def process_file(fname):
    mols = Read(fname)
    if verbose: print 'read ', fname
    mol = mols[0]
    if len(mols)>1:
        if verbose: 
            print "more than one molecule in file"
        #use the one molecule with the most atoms
        ctr = 1
        for m in mols[1:]:
            ctr += 1
            if len(m.allAtoms)>len(mol.allAtoms):
                mol = m
                if verbose:
                    print "mol set to ", ctr, "th molecule with", len(mol.allAtoms), "atoms"
    coord_dict = {}
    for a in mol.allAtoms: coord_dict[a] = a.coords

    mol.buildBondsByDistance()
    if charges_to_add is not None:
        preserved = {}
        preserved_types = preserve_charge_types.split(',') 
        for t in preserved_types:
            if not len(t): continue
            ats = mol.allAtoms.get(lambda x: x.autodock_element==t)
            for a in ats:
                if a.chargeSet is not None:
                    preserved[a] = [a.chargeSet, a.charge]

    if verbose:
        print "setting up LPO with mode=", mode,
        print "and outputfilename= ", outputfilename
        print "and check_for_fragments=", check_for_fragments
        print "and bonds_to_inactivate=", bonds_to_inactivate
    LPO = AD4LigandPreparation(mol, mode, repairs, charges_to_add, 
                            cleanup, allowed_bonds, root, 
                            outputfilename=outputfilename,
                            dict=dict, check_for_fragments=check_for_fragments,
                            bonds_to_inactivate=bonds_to_inactivate, 
                            inactivate_all_torsions=inactivate_all_torsions,
                            attach_nonbonded_fragments=attach_nonbonded_fragments)
    #do something about atoms with too many bonds (?)
    #FIX THIS: could be peptide ligand (???)
    #          ??use isPeptide to decide chargeSet??
    if charges_to_add is not None:
        #restore any previous charges
        for atom, chargeList in preserved.items():
            atom._charges[chargeList[0]] = chargeList[1]
            atom.chargeSet = chargeList[0]
    if verbose: print "returning ", mol.returnCode 
    bad_list = []
    for a in mol.allAtoms:
        if a.coords!=coord_dict[a]: bad_list.append(a)
    if len(bad_list):
        print len(bad_list), ' atom coordinates changed!'    
        for a in bad_list:
            print a.name, ":", coord_dict[a], ' -> ', a.coords
    else:
        if verbose: print "No change in atomic coordinates"
    if mol.returnCode != 0: 
        sys.stderr.write(mol.returnMsg + "\n")
    # sys.exit(mol.returnCode)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import getopt

    def usage():
        "Print helpful, accurate usage statement to stdout."
        print "Usage: prepare_ligand4.py -l filename"
        print
        print "    Description of command..."
        print "         -l     ligand_filename       (.pdb or .mol2 or .pdbq format)"
        print "         -i     list_of_filenames.txt (.pdb or .mol2 or .pdbq format)"
        print "    Optional parameters:"
        print "        [-v]    verbose output"
        print "        [-o pdbqt_filename] (default output filename is ligand_filename_stem + .pdbqt)"
        print "        [-d]    dictionary to write types list and number of active torsions "

        print "        [-A]    type(s) of repairs to make:\n\t\t bonds_hydrogens, bonds, hydrogens (default is to do no repairs)"
        print "        [-C]    do not add charges (default is to add gasteiger charges)"
        print "        [-p]    preserve input charges on atom type, eg -p Zn"
        print "               (default is not to preserve charges on any specific atom type)"
        print "        [-U]    cleanup type:\n\t\t nphs_lps, nphs, lps, '' (default is 'nphs_lps') "
        print "        [-B]    type(s) of bonds to allow to rotate "
        print "               (default sets 'backbone' rotatable and 'amide' + 'guanidinium' non-rotatable)"
        print "        [-R]    index for root"
        print "        [-F]    check for and use largest non-bonded fragment (default is not to do this)"
        print "        [-M]    interactive (default is automatic output)"
        print "        [-I]    string of bonds to inactivate composed of "
        print "                   of zero-based atom indices eg 5_13_2_10  "
        print "                   will inactivate atoms[5]-atoms[13] bond "
        print "                               and atoms[2]-atoms[10] bond "
        print "                      (default is not to inactivate any specific bonds)"
        print "        [-Z]    inactivate all active torsions     "
        print "                      (default is leave all rotatable active except amide and guanidinium)"
        print "        [-g]    attach all nonbonded fragments "
        print "                      (default is not to do this)"

    # process command arguments
    try:
        opt_list, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'l:i:vo:d:A:Cp:U:B:R:MFI:Zgh')
    except getopt.GetoptError, msg:
        print 'prepare_ligand4.py: %s' %msg
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)

    #'l:vo:d:A:CKU:B:R:MFI:Zg'
    for o, a in opt_list:
        #print "o=", o, " a=", a
        if o in ('-l', '--l'):
            ligand_filename = a
            if verbose: print 'set ligand_filename to ', a
        if o in ('-i', '--i'):
            ligand_listfile = a
            if verbose: print 'set ligand_listfile to ', a
        if o in ('-v', '--v'):
            verbose = True
            if verbose: print 'set verbose to ', True
        if o in ('-o', '--o'):
            outputfilename = a
            if verbose: print 'set outputfilename to ', a
        if o in ('-d', '--d'):
            dict = a
            if verbose: print 'set dict to ', a
        if o in ('-A', '--A'):
            repairs = a
            if verbose: print 'set repairs to ', a
        if o in ('-C', '--C'):
            charges_to_add = None
            if verbose: print 'do not add charges'
        if o in ('-p', '--p'):
            preserve_charge_types+=a
            preserve_charge_types+=','
            if verbose: print 'preserve initial charges on ', preserve_charge_types
        if o in ('-U', '--U'):
            cleanup  = a
            if verbose: print 'set cleanup to merge ', a
        if o in ('-B', '--B'):
            allowed_bonds = a
            if verbose: print 'allow ', a, 'bonds set to rotate'
        if o in ('-R', '--R'):
            root = a
            if verbose: print 'set root to ', root
        if o in ('-F', '--F'):
            check_for_fragments = True
            if verbose: print 'set check_for_fragments to True'
        if o in ('-M', '--M'):
            mode = a
            if verbose: print 'set mode to ', a
        if o in ('-I', '--I'):
            bonds_to_inactivate = a
            if verbose: print 'set bonds_to_inactivate to ', a
        if o in ('-Z', '--Z'):
            inactivate_all_torsions = True
            if verbose: print 'set inactivate_all_torsions to ', inactivate_all_torsions
        if o in ('-g', '--g'):
            attach_nonbonded_fragments = True
            if verbose: print 'set attach_nonbonded_fragments to ', attach_nonbonded_fragments
        if o in ('-h', '--'):
            usage()
            sys.exit()

    if ligand_filename:
        process_file(ligand_filename)
    elif ligand_listfile:
        # Python 2.5 does not support `with`
        # with open(ligand_listfile) as inf:
        #     for fname in inf:
        #         process_file(fname.rstrip())
        inf = open(ligand_listfile)
        for fname in inf:
            process_file(fname.rstrip())
        inf.close()
    else:
        print 'prepare_ligand4: either -l (ligand filename) or -i (ligand listfile) must be specified.'
        usage()
        sys.exit()

# To execute this command type:
# prepare_ligand4.py -l pdb_file -v
```

Comment: I'm making a save.tar which will take few hours. I'll try this out after. Thanks

Comment: setting PYTHONHOME environment
./prepare_ligand4v2.py:220: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
  File "./prepare_ligand4v2.py", line 220
    with open(ligand_listfile) as inf:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: (wince) apparently you are using Python 2.5 (circa 2008). I will update the script to not use `with`.

Comment: You did it. Thank you a lot!